# Where can I find iTunes 9 for Tiger (possibly in my language)?

Tags: itunes

I've an issue on a old Mac with Tiger.

I cannot upgrade iTunes to version 9. (I cannot find version 9, and I'm actually looking for the Italian version).

iTunes suggests to upgrade to 10, but this version doesn't work on Tiger. So it is suggesting an impossible update.

thanks

Comment: What does System Update do here - doesn't it find the newest iTunes that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to at least iTunes 9.1.1 for Mac http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1036

Answer (score 1):

Apple maintains [lists of download links of the older versions of their software](http://www.info.apple.com/support/oldersoftwarelist.html) from the Support section of their website. [Sometimes they come up in Google searches](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Apple+old+software&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), but they are hard to find no matter what. I've grabbed versions of iTunes for Mac OS 10.4 from their site recently, so start digging around their Support section.

**UPDATE:** Here is the page I was thinking of: http://support.apple.com/downloads/ Just search for the software you're looking for, it shouldn't be too hard to find there

Comment: Thanks, yeah I saw those links, but I cannot find iTunes 9